# Upgrading to latest clang compiler on older MacOS

Tags: xcode, macos, clang

Is it possible to update clang 12.0.0 running on an older MacBook that is running 10.15.7 to clang 14.2.0, the current version? I've tried using both xcode-select and softwareupdate to no avail. The former tells me command line tools are installed already while the latter doesn't report any updates. Because of the computer's age, Apple isn't providing updates any more so I'm stuck there nor can I install the latest xcode updates.